# Не могу создать FXML в Intellij IDEA

Tags: javafx

вот так это выглядит у меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а так мне нужно

Answer (score 1):

попробуй эту инструкцию:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-fxml-files-in-javafx-scene-builder.html

должно получится

или эту:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#run